# how to load js widget file in dojo ? registerModulePath is working but in 1.8 packages not working - need help immediately

Tags: dojo, dojo-1.9, dojo-1.8

Hello need help immediately,
I have web directory as

```
- WebContent
    index.jsp
    dojo
    testjs
        - bpl
            - mywidget.js
```

Context path  is  `/TestWeb/CheckDojo`

script in `index.jsp`:

```
dojo.registerModulePath("testjs","/TestWeb/CheckDojo/testjs");
```

is working and i can do

```
require([ "dojo/dom",  "testjs/bpl/mywidget", "dojo/domReady!"], ...
```

but in dojo 1.8 , 
in dojoconfig i am using

```
data-dojo-config="locale:                  en-us,
                  async:                   true,            
                  config-tlmSiblingOfDojo: false, 
                  packages: [{
                              name: 'testjs', 
                              location: '/TestWeb/CheckDojo/testjs'
                            }],
                  parseOnLoad: true"
```

then in require mywidget is searched in dojo directory which is not the correct path.

what and how should i load the package ?

Answer (score 0):

Look here [enter link description here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/loader/amd.html) (module indentifiers). The documentation tells that the location is relative of the 'dojo' folder (defined in dojo.baseUrl).

You should change the code to :

```
data-dojo-config="locale:                  en-us,
              async:                   true,            
              config-tlmSiblingOfDojo: false, 
              packages: [{
                          name: 'testjs', 
                          location: '../TestWeb/CheckDojo/testjs'
                        }],
              parseOnLoad: true"
```